# What type is chosen for a polymorphic expression when printed?

Tags: haskell, ghci

What is the type of `return "abc"` when printed in ghci?

The point of the question is that it's polymorphic in the monad:

```
ghci> :t return "abc"
return "abc" :: (Monad m) => m [Char]
```

and what gets printed depends on which monad is chosen:

```
ghci> return "abc" :: Maybe String
Just "abc"

ghci> return "abc" :: [] String
["abc"]
```

but here's what's actually printed:

```
ghci> return "abc"
"abc"
```

Comment: IO. An ghci session is like a special huge IO Monad!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you type an expression `expr` into GHCi, the following things happen:

- The expression is type-checked. If there is an error, GHCi tells you the error and gives up.
- Otherwise, say `expr` is found to have type `t`; GHC tries to match `t` against `IO a`.
- If it succeeds, then it executes something like `it <- expr`, then if `a` is an instance of `Show` and is not `()`, it executes `print it`.
- If it fails, and `t` itself is an instance of `Show`, GHCi does something like `let it = expr` and then `print it`.
- Otherwise, it complains.

Essentially, you need a way at the GHCi prompt both of running IO actions and getting at the values they return, and of playing around with pure values and seeing what you get. That's why GHCi behaves the way it does: if it seems like you're using an IO action, GHCi will do it, and then if that action has a result that can be shown and is interesting (i.e. not `()`) then it shows the result to you. If it can't show the result to you, then it's no big deal, because you probably just wanted to run the IO action anyway; if you wanted the result you would have named it with `<-`. On the other hand, if it seems like your expression is *not* an IO action, GHCi calculates it and shows it to you, and if it can't be shown then GHCi can't do anything useful (no side-effects this time), so complains.

In this case, `return "abc"` typechecks as `IO String`, and `String` is an instance of `Show`, so GHCi does something like

```
it <- return "abc"
print it
```

which by the monad laws is exactly the same as just doing

```
print "abc"
```

hence the result.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell has a slightly baffling set of rules for deciding the types of expressions involving numbers; you can see the [Report section on ambiguous types and default instances](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4).  So the answer to the general question is complicated.  But within GHCi, if you enter an expression *e*, you can rely on these rules to apply:

- If the expression *e* can be typed as `IO T` for some type `T`, and if `T` has a `Show` instance, GHCi will run the computation and print the resulting value of type `T`.  That's what's happening in your third example.
- If the expression *e* *cannot* be typed in the `IO` monad, then the default-instance rules come into play, and GHCi will choose a type according to those rules.  If the type has a `Show` instance GHCi will then print `show` *e*.  That's what happens in your first two examples: `Maybe String` and `[String]` are pure values with `Show` instances.

  If *e*'s type does *not* have a `Show` instance, then GHCi will complain.  That will happen if you type an expression like `flip take`.

Comment: I think the fact that the question is clearly about ghci and the rules are different there makes the first couple of sentences misleading. Furthermore, GHCi does not try to print the results of `IO` actions you type in if the relevant type is not `Show`able, or if it is `()`. I'm not sure if there aren't more rules as well. Also, GHCi's defaulting rules are stronger than standard Haskell's.